# Mapstruct and Lombok upgrade results in different initialization behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I recently upgraded Lombok from 1.16.22 to 1.18.20, Spring boot from 2.1.13 to 2.2.13, and Mapstruct from 1.2.0 to 1.4.2 and started seeing this odd behavior.

```
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Basket {

    ...
    private List<Discount> discounts = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    public Basket(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Prior to the upgrades, "discounts" would be initialized with an empty ArrayList when the single argument constructor is called. However, now I am seeing that "discounts" has an initial value of null. I am trying to narrow down the upgrade or thing that's causing this change in behavior, but I don't know where to start. I am using neither the mapper logic or generated constructors when I call the single parameter constructor. Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: MapStruct works by generating `.java` files. You can inspect them and see if they're doing something like explicitly setting these values.

Comment: This seems odd. Did you try to delombok the class?

Comment: Try putting `@Builder.Default` or `@Singular` on `discounts`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, faced a similar issue while trying to use mapstruct and lombok, we faced issue with mapstruct not able to use the .java files to create mapping.

This is due to lombok @Builder annotation. Lombok also generates these methods, constructors and builders in compile time and it was not been found by mapstruct.
My two cents would be to debug by replacing lombok annotation impl with your own first and debug.